# NSPredicate that references multiple fields on a to-many relationship?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-data, nspredicate

I'm using a SQLite persistent store.  I have a `NSManagedObject` class `Den` with a to-many relationship `Bear`.  `Bear` has several fields:

```
Bear:
    breed
    color
    age
    ...
```

When I am building fetch requests for my `Den` objects, I can filter to objects that have a related `Bear` with a certain field value:

```
NSPredicate *hasGrizzlyPred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY Bear.breed == 'grizzly'"];
```

Or I can just as easily search for a `Den` that has a brown bear:

```
NSPredicate *hasBrownBearPred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY Bear.color == 'brown'"];
```

But is there any way to search for a `Den` that has a bear that is both brown and a grizzly?  The following is legal, but incorrect, I think:

```
// Not quite right: search for a den with a brown bear AND a grizzly
NSPredicate *hasBrownAndGrizzlyPred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY Bear.color == 'brown' AND ANY Bear.breed == 'grizzly'"];
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this with a [`SUBQUERY`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSExpression_Class/Reference/NSExpression.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001190-SW22) predicate expression. In the case of a query for dens with a bear (where `Den` has a to-many relationship to `Bear` named `bears`) that is both brown and a grizzly:

`[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SUBQUERY(bears, $b, $b.color=='brown' AND $b.breed=='grizzly').@count > 0"];`

Comment: The Core Data documentation leaves me... frustrated at times.  This is perfect.

Comment: I've pointed many folks to the `NSExpression` documentation. Please file a bug report at bugreporter.apple.com on the documentation and suggest how it might have been presented so that you could have found it sooner.

Comment: it's possibile to save that .@count value?